# What do employers look for in a math PhD with a PDE/Complex Analysis background?

Tags: phd, mathematics, job, industry

I'm currently in the 4th year of my PhD in math. My main research focus is complex analysis (geometric function theory) but I'm also learning and working on PDE modelling. After my PhD, I want to apply for an industry job that is (at least somewhat) research oriented. Ideally, I would like to apply/develop Partial Differential Equation (PDE) modelling as part of the job. I'm at a fork in my path where I believe it is more beneficial to go the PDE route for industry. (Although complex analysis has a long history of applications in almost every science.)

My two questions are:

1. How do I find out what are some of the current, most cutting-edge PDE techniques used in the industry? Of course, I talk to my academic mentors but I feel like there's a semipermeable wall between academia and industry where knowledge and information flows only from academia to the industry and not the other way.
2. What are some skills that potential employers look for from a math PhD with a PDE background?

I realize this question is too narrow in that it focuses only on jobs that apply PDEs but I welcome comments and answers from related fields; say, calculus of variations or numerical analysis.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This seems to be a question about industry, not academia. Maybe the Workplace would be a better home for it: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If your interest is in partial differential equations, probably your best bet is to demonstrate your familiarity with established methods for numerical solution, maybe mesh generation. As far as straight-up mathematical modeling goes, explore specialized contractors who provide that service to others.

Comment: You're asking the wrong place, even the "applied" mathematics departments are basically completely disconnected from doing substantially useful things.

Comment: @FourierFlux Departments consist of people, and good departments have at least some people who have their finger on the pulse of what the world outside academia is actually doing.

Comment: I'll add to my previous comment: A would-be employer also likely would look for decent software development skills and some sort of awareness of common development practices.

Comment: I'm not, when I was considering going to PhD in mathematics the program director I talked to said, "if you want to build things become an engineer, if you want to model things become a physicist, if you want to prove things become a mathematician".

Comment: Well, yes, @FourierFlux's comments are largely correct, namely, that people saying they do "applied math" are all too often merely expressing a conceit, or some sort of oppositeness to other parts of math they "don't like/understand", and use this as a label. But _some_ good applied math people really do things that are applicable. :)  (Stupidly, all too often, math-that-is-applied does not meet insiders' criterion to be "applied math". Ridiculous abuse of language.)

Comment: @FourierFlux Then, first, that program director was a moron. Second, that person had no overview of what mathematicians really do and only considered their own academic bubble. The vast majority of math undergraduate majors do not become professors, but end up in careers outside academia that are fulfilling and appreciated by their employers; they do not prove theorems there, by and large, but are valued members of teams that model, build, test, analyze, etc. It's silly to suggest that "mathematicians prove theorems". It's a disservice to the profession to claim that that's what they do.

Comment: I personally found that an undergrad math degree was basically useless by itself, I would not recommend anyone get one as a stand alone degree.

Answer (score 3):

There is much information flowing back from industry to academia as well, though maybe not enough to mathematics specifically.

Regardless, the #1 skill we know industry employers need from math graduates (PhD or undergraduate) are computer skills in general, programming skills in particular, and in the context of PDEs skills with the numerical solution of differential equations.

If you are interested in a cross section of applications of computing in industry, for example, you might be interested in taking a look at [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1466596805).

Answer (score 1):

Almost by definition, no cutting-edge things are done in industry, because all too frequently the company doing the cutting-edge things is what ends up being cut.

Providing a proof of anything is almost always way overkill for industry; it takes too much time and effort for little improvement, and in the unlikely event that something they relied on turns out to be false, bankruptcy is not that bad an option.  (Everyone still gets to keep what they were already paid as salary.)

Unfortunately, the few exceptions tend to involve blowing up people.

Comment: This answer has no relationship to the question, but it's also bizarrely uninformed and wrong in claiming "Almost by definition, no cutting-edge things are done in industry". The light bulb, the telephone, the microchip were all invented by companies, to give just a very very short list. I would suggest to also read up on the history of Bell Labs, for a much longer one.

Comment: Any CEO that tried to start a Bell Labs at their company nowadays would be instantly fired by their shareholders - basic research is that clearly a bad return on investment.  Things were different when companies had the monopoly power to make lots of money on their own big innovations.

Comment: Have you looked at the research budgets of companies like Intel? Or the ones that build the machines that are used to fabricate computer chips?

Comment: Almost all of what Intel calls "research spending" is something I would call "development spending".